# Setting CSS properties in GWT

Tags: css, gwt

I need to set the the **-moz-box-sizing** property on a widget through my GWT code. I don't want to do this through the .css file but need to do it in my java code. I tried

> widget.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("mozBoxSizing",
>   "border-box")

, but that doesn't work. Does anyone know how to convert **-moz-box-sizing** to the property camelcase property for GWT?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems MozBoxSizing would be the correct camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with that widget.getElement().setAttribute("style","mozBoxSizing:border-box"); ?